# How to get total count of each month in return using entity framework core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get the count of instances of each month given a dataset and am having trouble coming up with a solution.

Here is my model from entity framework

```
public class Data 
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Time { get; set; }
   public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

This is my method

```
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Result>> GetDates()
{
   IEnumerable<string> dates = _Database.result.Select(r => r.Date);
   IEnumerable<int> totalResult= _Database.result.Select(r => r.Date).Count();
   return Ok(date);
}
```

Comment: _I am using date as a string_ - if you want to group by (ie get the count per month) then you must parse the string as a date

Comment: `.Count(); //this will get me array of object` - what? Count [returns an integer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count)

Comment: yea sorry my bad, its the int it returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just use a GroupBy if you are interested in every months count

```
var dates = _Database.result.Select(r => r.Date).ToList();
IEnumerable<int> monthGrp = dates
   .GroupBy(e => DateTime.Parse(e).Month)
   .Select(e => e.Count());
```

Comment: :( same error :
    .GroupBy(
        keySelector: r => DateTime.Parse(r.Date).Month, 
        elementSelector: r => r.Date)' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'System.DateTime.Parse' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function,
Translation of method 'System.DateTime.Parse' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function,  Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

Comment: hmm error sounds familiar I am guessing you are using Entity Framework? Made an adjustment to my answer that should sort out this error

Comment: Perfect man, it works yea i was using entity frame work, Thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah keep in mind that entity framework is differed execution, by not enumerating we were just adding to the query.. and SQL doesn't understand DateTime.Parse()

Answer (score 0):

Where you have:

```
var totalResult= _Database.result.Select(r => r.Date).Count();
```

You should change it to this:

```
var totalResults = _Database.result
          .Where(r => DateTime.Parse(r.Date).Month == 4)
          .Count();
```

You could also just do this:

```
var totalResults = _Database.result
           .Count(r => DateTime.Parse(r.Date).Month == 4);
```

This will parse the `Date` property into a `DateTime` object and will filter the results where `DateTime.Month` is equal to 4 and then get the count. You could remove the `Select()` in the Linq statement as it is not necessary to retrieve certain properties if all you want is the count.

`Count()` will return an `int` value not an array.

Comment: This can use Count directly as the method can [take the condition as the parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Count__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__)  - `.Count(r => DateTime.Parse(r.Date).Month == 4)`

Comment: Good to know. Thanks, I will add that to my answer.

Comment: That answer won't work right cause that's using DateTime whereas I am using the date as a string? I Might be wrong or not make sense lol. I used that code anyways and I got ".Where(r => DateTime.Parse(r.Date).Month == 4)' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'System.DateTime.Parse' failed." . Sorry i am just new to coding trying my best to understand and work with it

Comment: That is interesting, is there any errors when you compile/build? Or does it occur during runtime? And the reason for doing this, is it is a DateTime.Parse so it will take your string value and Parse it into a DateTime object.

Comment: it occurs when I hit execute in swagger .net core. If I build no errors. it's after I hit the endpoint to retrieve data. Oh i get you , thanks for extra bit of information at the end.

Comment: If it happens during runtime, then I imagine there is probably null data, try this to filter the bad data out:
`.Where(r => !String.IsNullOrWhitespace(r.Date) && DateTime.Parse(r.Date).Month == 4)`
This will fetch the data that is not null or whitespace, then parse it into a DateTime.

Comment: @jaabh still same error `System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Reserve>()
    .Where(r => !(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Date)) && DateTime.Parse(r.Date).Month == 4)' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'System.DateTime.Parse' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information.
Translation of method 'System.DateTime.Parse' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function`

Comment: Im not sure. I do not get any errors when I do it. Are there any errors during compilation (before you execute and run it)? If so then work through those errors, if not then there could be something wrong with DbSet